# Unable to locate package cloud-client

Tags: package-management, cloud, owncloud-client

I want to create a cloud service using CloudStack on Ubuntu 12.04. But, when I try to install management server using this command :

```
sudo apt-get install cloud-client
```

I get this as output,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cloud-client
```

Comment: have you added their PPA? since they don't seem to be in the repositories by standard.

Answer (score 0):

`cloud-front` is not available for Ubuntu 12.04!

You can find the 13.04 version [here.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cloud-client)

Answer (score 0):

> ownCloud client allows you to specify one ore more directories on the
>   local machine to sync your ownCloud server, and always have your
>   latest files wherever you are. Make a change to the files on one
>   computer, it will flow across the others using these desktop sync
>   clients.

To install click [**ownCloud client** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/owncloud-client/)

<sup>Source:Ubuntu Apps</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You might want check in your sources list `/etc/apt/sources.list` that the Cloudstack repo (`deb http://cloudstack.apt-get.eu/ubuntu precise 4.0`) is in there!

You could also do `grep deb http://cloudstack.apt-get.eu/ubuntu precise 4.0 /etc/apt/sources.list` to see if its in there or not!

Note: in the example given I assume that you're using *Ubuntu 12.04 Precise*, which is said in Cloudstack to work best with their configs.